# W3C validation differs when validated by HTML & URL

Tags: asp.net, validation, devexpress, w3c-validation

I have a Website using DevX controls. When I copy the page source of the rendered page and validate the same [here](http://validator.w3.org/), it shows no errors. If I try to validate the same page by passing URL to this page, W3C starts showing me some errors based on the code which doesn't exist on the page.

From a different forum in DevExpress, I found that

> The matter is that when the validator (http://validator.w3.org/check)
>   requests a page to check, it generates rather specific userAgent
>   information. This client agent is identified by the Table control's
>   render logic not entirely correctly, and so, invalid markup is present
>   in the final code.

Is there any way to tell W3C to use specific UserAgent while validating or are there any other modes to eradicate these kind of errors?

Comment: Are you using a layout page?

Comment: Yes a master and content page

Comment: While pasting the HTML, are you pasting the master page also? If not, then just open the page and view source in browser and paste the whole source.

Comment: I am pasting the HTML code form "View Source" and it works fine. But when I try to validate by entering the page URL, it fails :(

Comment: The Nu HTML Checker (which is the new validator by the W3C that is taking over the legacy validator) has an option to pass the User Agent string - https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: Thanks, will check this out.